# Passing a Stream from Server to Client

Tags: c#, stream, server

I have a scenario where the Uri to media content contains my super secret App Token (expires in 10 min, treat it like a credit card, etc.). The result of going to that Uri is an mp3 stream. I would like to server this stream to my web client, but I absolutely cannot give them the Uri. Are there any alternatives to (1) downloading the stream and then serving it again to the client, or (2) streaming to my server and simultaneously streaming to the client.

I suppose it is possible to run down a Token so that it has like 30 seconds left on it and then pass that to the user. Maybe that is possibility (3).

Comment: Your server can act as a proxy and the file could be accessed with another uri through your server...

Comment: Ahh, that is not a bad idea. Though it is something like (2). Maybe the only real option. So the idea would be to send the client http://myserver.com/abcdef12345 and it would be routed to http://secretserver/?token=blahblah&q=blahblah

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: I haven't chosen anything yet. But usually MVC. I think what I'll do is when the request is generated, I will add to a Dictionary of hash to target uri. Then the user will go to http://myserver.com/?hash=xxx and get routed to http://secretserver/?toke=blahblah&q=blahblah. Once it is used once, the hash is removed from the dictionary.